# Что означает данный фрагмент кода?

Tags: c#, devexpress

[image]

Как объяснить эту строку ?
Источник:https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument2257

Comment: Это? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Comment: @netrox, а ниже там на раздел Results посмотреть в туториале?

Comment: Это же просто создание нового обьекта типа Order, ну и передача его в метод

Comment: Создание нового объекта типа Order это понятно,но я не понял "customer1.Orders"

Comment: @netrox судя по всему Orders у вас это коллекция типа (класса) Order. В выделенном вами фрагменте идёт добавление нового заказа в список заказов. customer - клиент (англ.) - экземпляр класса Customer.

Comment: Почему у коллекции Orders тип данных Order ?

Comment: List<Order> Orders = new List<Order>(); ну как-то так

Answer (score 2):

Этот фрагмент кода можно также написать таким образом :

```
Order temp = new Order(session1);
temp.ProductName = "Chai";
temp.OrderTime = new DateTime(2013, 3, 11);
customer1.Orders.Add(temp);
```

Здесь в объект customer1.Orders типа 
`IEnumerable<Order>` (скорее всего список) добавляется новый объект с параметрами :

```
ProductName == "Chai"
OrderTime == new DateTime(2013, 3, 11) //11-ое марта 2013 года
```

При вызове конструктора класса Order (при создании объекта класса Order) , задается параметр session1.